# How to read the content of a file after a pattern found ?(unix)

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

i have a file that contains some text with comments i have to change the text ending with a special character to something else without changing any comment

example

```
------this is a comment1---
rose#
marigold#
------this is a comment2---
dog#
cat#
------pattern-------
------this is a comment3---
brazil
is awesome#
america#
```

what i needed

1.look for  the "-----pattern----" start reading from there

2.skip the comments

3.store the string(important) in a variable till "#" is found.ADD "$" if the string start with vowel.

4.keep doing till the end of file

My final file should look like this

```
------this is a comment1---
rose#
marigold#
------this is a comment2---
dog#
cat#
------pattern-------
------this is a comment3---
brazil
is awesome#
$america#
```

this is what i have tried

```
awk '/----Pattern----/'{
while IFS="#" read -r LINE || [[ -n "$LINE" ]]; do
    if echo "$LINE" |grep -q '^--'; then
    continue
    else if echo "$LINE" |grep -q '^a'; then
       LINE="$""$LINE"

done

} file.txt
```

Comment: Is this literally just "write a program for me"?

Comment: and why should `is awesom` not be preceeded with `$` (it's also vowel) ? Also, post the actual format of your comments `------this is a comment2---`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest only the first character is needed to be test.comment start with atleast 2 dash and end with -- with new line

Comment: @deepakpandey `is` starts with vowel

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest brazil /n is awsome is a single string .ending with "#" hence i have to check only b of brazil

Comment: And what happens when you try to *run* the code you have written? How would *you* interpret the errors it's giving you?

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you posted from the input you posted all you need (using GNU awk for multi-char RS) is:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="#\n"} {print (/^[aeiou]/ ? "$" : "") $0}' file
------this is a comment1---
rose#
marigold#
------this is a comment2---
dog#
cat#
------pattern-------
------this is a comment3---
brazil
is awesome#
$america#
```

If that's not adequate for your real input then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

In awk

```
$ awk '
/pattern/ { f=1 }                       # flag up at pattern
f=="" || /^--.*--$/ { print; next }    # just print pre-flagged, comments and pattern
f { b=b (b==""?"":ORS) $0               # buffer after flag
    if(b~/#$/) {                        # once buffers ends with #
        print (b~/^[aeiouy]/?"$":"") b  # print buffer with $ where needed
        b=""                            # reset buffer
    }
}' file
...
------this is a comment3---
brazil
is awesome#
$america#
```